# Rails 3.0.12 remote form failing with AJAX update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, file-upload

Using Ruby 1.8.7-p358, Rails 3.0.12, gem responder, gem simple-form; jquery_ujs.js

I have a form where :remote=>true and also uploading a file

```
= simple_form_for :resume, :url => {:controller => :resumes,
action => :upload_resume, :id => @job_seeker.id}, :html => { :multipart => true }, :remote => true do |f|
etc
```

The Resume controller method looks like this:

```
respond_to :html, :xml, :json, :js

def upload_resume
  r = @job_seeker.resumes.new
  r.name          = params[:resume][:name]
  r.source_path   = params[:resume][:content].original_filename
  r.doc_type      = params[:resume][:content].content_type
  r.content       = params[:resume][:content].tempfile.read
  r.size          = r.content.size
  r.source_ip     = request.remote_ip
  r.save
,end
```

which it does, but will not respond to upload_resume.js.erb, which looks like this:

```
$('#resume_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'resumes/resumes' ))%>");
```

Is there anything about data-remote & file uploads that causes the render to misbehave?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved the issue by converting erb to haml